# Detect if a zone.js patch is loaded?

Tags: javascript, angular, zone.js, zonejs

Hi I need to find a way to detect that an app imports `zone-patch-fetch`.

It's imported like following : `import 'zone.js/plugins/zone-patch-fetch';`

Is there a way to do that ?.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7bk5qf?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: You can add onLoad to your script and use its callback to change state to "loaded"

Comment: @PCPbiscuit I'm not sure you understand how `zone.js` works.

Comment: To be 100% sure, you are talking about this right ? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f2926b19e84f94a2d66a35e7cb4ab394a4ba7bb1/packages/zone.js/lib/common/fetch.ts#L13

Comment: @Wandrille Exactly !

Comment: Huh, interesting. Can you not directly access `Zone.current` internals to check this?

Comment: I've checked both the global scope and Zone and found nothing.

Comment: `console.log((globalThis as any).fetch('').then());` returns a `ZoneAwarePromise` object. Could it be enough to know that It's well defined?